# How to publish referenced projects within an ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, publish

I'm building an ASP.NET web portal for a project for school.

I use a three tier architecture and I'm trying to publish it using FTP.
The web project is published successfully but the other two projects aren't published on the IIS.

How can I tell visual studio that I want these projects published alongside the web project?

here is an image to make it a bit more clear

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXPl5.png

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No need to publish other projects separately.

1. Give reference of other project to your main project.
2. Publish Main Project.
3. DLL's of all projects will get created in bin folder[you will get this folder in publish folder].
4. Just upload files in bin folder to FTP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to publish the class library projects.
All you have to do is to add references of your class library projects in your web application and publish it. It'll add your class library projects dll in bin folder of your published folder.